# chrome remote debugger execute javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom, websocket, google-chrome-devtools

I launched chrome in debug mode and connected to it with websockets and could navigate wit method : page.navigate 
but I want to execute some javascripts on the websites I go to so I'm lookin for a method in this protocol to execute javascript

Answer (score 1):

How about [Runtime.callFunctionOn()](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Runtime/#method-callFunctionOn) or [Runtime.evaluate()](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Runtime/#method-evaluate) or [Runtime.runScript()](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Runtime/#method-runScript)?